# How to simulate a key event with modifier key pressed in an Ember.js integration test?

Tags: testing, ember.js

I'm trying to test an event handler that reacts to the `shift` + `delete` key combo, but [the Ember docs for the `Test.keyEvent` method](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Test.html#method_keyEvent) don't seem to mention any way to activate modifier keys.

I tried issuing a `keydown` on `shift` (keyCode 16), then `keydown` on `delete` (keyCode 46):

```
keyEvent('.my input', 'keydown', 16);  // Shift
keyEvent('.my input', 'keydown', 46);  // Delete
keyEvent('.my input', 'keyup', 46);  // Delete
keyEvent('.my input', 'keyup', 16);  // Shift
```

but the delete event's `shiftKey` property is still undefined

Comment: Notice that what you are naming _integration test_ is what in ember terminology is called _acceptance test_ -- integration tests should do `this.$('input').val('test'); this.$('input').trigger('keyup');` -- as shown in [this guide example](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/testing/testing-components/#toc_waiting-on-asynchronous-behavior)

Answer (score 6):

It seems the answer is to use `triggerEvent` instead of `keyEvent`:

```
triggerEvent('.my input', 'keydown', {
  keyCode: 46,  // Delete
  shiftKey: true
});
```

Comment: This also works for clicks. A list of keyboard event properties can be found here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent , for example `metaKey: true` is what you want for the Windows or Command key (Mac). To simulate a windows or mac "command" keydown plus click use:

  `triggerEvent('.my input', 'click', {
    metaKey: true
  });`

Comment: @Gabriel Should not the `keydown` also follow up with a `keyup` to complete the `keyevent`?

Comment: @lft93ryt technically, yes. in my case i only actually needed the `keydown`, though